# Postgres DISTINCT Query issue

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Users"."id" , "Users".name,
  "Users"."surname", "Users"."gender",
  "Users"."dob", "Searches"."start_date"
FROM "Users"
  LEFT JOIN "Searches" ON "Users"."id" = "Searches"."user_id"
WHERE (SQRT( POW(69.1 * ("Users"."latitude" - 45.465454), 2) + POW(69.1 * (9.186515999999983 - "Users"."longitude") * COS("Users"."latitude" / 57.3), 2))) < 20
  AND "Users"."status" = true
  AND "Users"."id" != 18
  AND "Searches"."activity" = \'clubbing\'
  AND "Users"."gender" = \'m\'
  AND "Users"."age" BETWEEN 18 AND 30
ORDER BY ABS( "Searches"."start_date"  - date \'2016-07-07\' )
```

For some reasons the above query returns the following error:

```
for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

I only want to return unique users but I really don't know what's wrong with it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is it in the error message that you do not understand?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't know what to do since I don't see any error. The start_date is already in the SELECT list

Comment: . . It might require that the entire expression be in the `select`.

Comment: `\'m\'` is invalid. Single quotes don't need escaping in SQL

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use `DISTINCT ON` to get one row per user id:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (u."id") u."id", u.name, u."surname", u."gender", u."dob", s."start_date"
FROM "Users" u LEFT JOIN
     "Searches" s
     ON u."id" = s."user_id"
WHERE (SQRT( POW(69.1 * (u."latitude" - 45.465454), 2) + POW(69.1 * (9.186515999999983 - u."longitude") * COS(u."latitude" / 57.3), 2))) < 20 AND
      u."status" = true AND
      u."id" != 18 AND "Searches"."activity" = \'clubbing\' AND
      u."gender" = \'m\' AND
      u."age" BETWEEN 18 AND 30
ORDER BY users.id, ABS(s."start_date"  - date \'2016-07-07\' );
```

Notice how table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Now I am getting this error: error: syntax error at or near ","

Answer (score 0):

Just doing what the error message says I would include the expression `ABS( "Searches"."start_date"  - date '2016-07-07' )` in the `SELECT` list.  No need to change your query logic.
`absdiffdate` can be discarded later when processing the result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT "Users"."id" , "Users".name,
  "Users"."surname", "Users"."gender",
  "Users"."dob", "Searches"."start_date",
  ABS( "Searches"."start_date"  - date '2016-07-07' ) absdiffdate
FROM "Users"
  LEFT JOIN "Searches" ON "Users"."id" = "Searches"."user_id"
WHERE (SQRT( POW(69.1 * ("Users"."latitude" - 45.465454), 2) + POW(69.1 * (9.186515999999983 - "Users"."longitude") * COS("Users"."latitude" / 57.3), 2))) < 20
  AND "Users"."status" = true
  AND "Users"."id" != 18
  AND "Searches"."activity" = 'clubbing'
  AND "Users"."gender" = 'm'
  AND "Users"."age" BETWEEN 18 AND 30
ORDER BY ABS( "Searches"."start_date"  - date '2016-07-07' )
```

Will this new column results in possibly more records when `DISTINCT` is applied?
I don't think so because you are subtracting a constant from start_date and for similar start_date corresponds similar outcome.